Long running process with shared and synced status between multiple browser windows?
is it practical to store the status of a long running process in a redis key to sync the status of process across multiple browser windows of the same page? ( including new browser windows opened when the process is running [ gets the status from the redis key] )
I am currently using socket.io to update process status to frontend (react)
The Long running process is using worker threads of nodejs ( wont block the main process )
The Flow:

Long running process worker (worker threads) starts
A new redis key (example name: process_running) will be created when the process starts
socket.io > informs frontend (All opened browser windows) > process started [ Frontend: Display processing... in progress bar ]
If > new browser window opened while process is running
New browser window > calls API > check if redis key (process_running) exist? If exist [ Display processing... in a progress bar ] : If not exist [ Hide progress bar]
IF: long running process worker (worker threads) encounters error > Deletes redis key (process_running) [ Process ended ]
socket.io > informs frontend (All opened browser windows) > process encountered an error [ Frontend: Display process failed in progress bar ]
IF: long running process worker (worker threads) completes with no errors (code === 0) > Deletes redis key (process_running) [ Process ended ]
socket.io > informs frontend (All opened browser windows) > process completed [ Frontend: Display success in a progress bar ]

Issue:
When nodejs crash before the redis key can be deleted, the redis key will still persist after nodejs is restarted, should I add a line of code in nodejs startup script to delete all redis key by pattern? because of this issue I am wondering if using redis is actually a good option, or is there some other better options out there?

please don't cross post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78532726/long-running-process-with-shared-and-synced-status-between-multiple-browser-wind

What concerns do you have with this solution? Asking if something is "practical" doesn't give us a problem to solve, and open-ended discussions do not fit the Q&A style of this community. Can you [edit] your question to focus on the problem with this design?

It sounds like you are adding extra bits you don't really need.
Instead of a redis cache lets say I add a dynamic endpoint the client can call 'status endpoint'
This endpoint is exposed by the long running process itself, so it can report directly back on its status by holding and updating it in memory.
This is the simplest way because it has no extra components. But say its impractical. The long running process, isn't a web server and cant talk direct with the clients.
But I can introduce a intermediary status endpoint, running on my server, which can be exposed but also connect to the long running process's status endpoint directly.
How to do interprocess communication in nodejs? reddis pub/sub.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463945/whats-the-most-efficient-node-js-inter-process-communication-library-method#12448328

It sounds like you want to report current status on an interactive
timescale, roughly similar to folks ssh'ing into a server
and doing $ ps wwup $(cat /var/run/daemon.pid).

When nodejs crash ...

Have a nanny script start the node worker process for you.
Being small, it's unlikely to crash.
It updates status to "not running" when its child process exits
for any reason.
This is robust to most things except powerfail,
and we have timeouts for that.
notification, not polling
The difficulty with repeatedly querying some Redis / Valkey record
is that either you're displaying somewhat stale info to interactive
users, or you're pounding the server with an unfortunately large number
of queries per minute, from multiple client machines.
In other words, when you're polling, you're always late.
Much better to switch from pull to push, as you have with socket.io.
A related approach with better failover properties would be to use a
pub-sub framework such as Kafka, RabbitMQ, or 0mq.
keepalive
But suppose you're following the "poll some key" approach.
You didn't mention the relevant timescales beyond having interactive users.
I will assume your worker process is able to send periodic
heartbeat messages every 2 seconds, 10 seconds, whatever.
And that it can conform to an SLA where, if heartbeats are late,
we consider it a dead failed worker.
Just have it keep writing current timestamp to same key,
which clients can query.
Now, suppose the worker host suffers powerfail. Typically when we
SET
a key we include a TTL which causes it to
EXPIRE
at some convenient time in the future.
If your batch jobs typically take a minute or two to complete,
then 300 seconds might be a convenient time-to-live for your use case.
That way, after a Bad Thing happens, everything is cleaned up
within five minutes of the unfortunate event.
